# Streambuilder returning null inside consumer

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

I am trying to pull data from firestore using streambuilder which is wrapped in a consumer like below. However, for some reason it is returning a null error.

I am confused why this is returning an error when I use consumer but works fine without it. Do I have to reference the collection differently when I use a consumer?

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _width = MediaQuery
        .of(context)
        .size
        .width;
    final _height = MediaQuery
        .of(context)
        .size
        .height;
return Consumer<CurrentModel>(builder: (context, currentModel, child) {
      return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection(currentModel.uid)
            .document(currentModel.uid).snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Stack(
children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                new Image.network(
                  snapshot.data['imageurl'].toString(),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
```

Stacktrace:

I/flutter (11582): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

```
I/flutter (11582): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(dirty, state:
I/flutter (11582): _StreamBuilderBaseState<DocumentSnapshot, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot>>#99271):
I/flutter (11582): The method '[]' was called on null.
I/flutter (11582): Receiver: null
I/flutter (11582): Tried calling: []("imageurl")
I/flutter (11582): 
I/flutter (11582): User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was:
I/flutter (11582):   Consumer<currentModel>
I/flutter (11582):   file:///Users/alexjasper/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_myapp/lib/main.dart:48:12
I/flutter (11582): 
I/flutter (11582): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (11582): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
I/flutter (11582): #1      DocumentSnapshot.[] (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:29:42)
I/flutter (11582): #2      _MyHomePageState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_myapp/main.dart:61:32)
I/flutter (11582): #3      StreamBuilder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:425:74)
I/flutter (11582): #4      _StreamBuilderBaseState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:125:48)
I/flutter (11582): #5      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4047:27)
I/flutter (11582): #6      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3941:15)
I/flutter (11582): #7      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3738:5)
I/flutter (11582): #8      BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2348:33)
I/flutter (11582): #9      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:760:20)
I/flutter (11582): #10     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:280:5)
I/flutter (11582): #11     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1033:15)
I/flutter (11582): #12     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:975:9)
I/flutter (11582): #13     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:891:5)
I/flutter (11582): #17     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:249:10)
I/flutter (11582): #18     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:207:3)
I/flutter (11582): (elided 3 frames from package dart:async)
I/flutter (11582): 
I/flutter (11582): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (11582): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
```

Comment: can you post your stacktrace with the error?

Comment: And the collection you are querying has the same "key" as the document you are looking for?

Comment: @Marc just posted the stack trace as well as additional code with key

Comment: can you do a print(snapshot) after the if (snapshot.hasData)  and post the console output here?

Comment: Did you get the solution for this? I am having same problem

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see anything wrong on your code. I think what's happening is that you don't have yet sinked any value on the stream. Maybe you could set an initialValue to the StreamBuilder to prevent this.

Comment: thank you, is this something like what you mean?                                           return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection(userModel.uid)
            .document(userModel.uid).snapshots(),
        initialData: 0,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {

Comment: Something like that, but what you probably want is a new DocumentSnapshot object as initalData and not number 0

Comment: if you would post the print() statement output as described above, tracking down the error would be far easier.